# Populating ComboBox with some data and then reading the selected row

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Good day all. I am trying to accomplish the following:

In a C# WinForm I am having a ComboBox.

In a local data-base I have some "groups" that after execution become folder in "D://" ( they are five )

After that in all the folders I have some files ( the number varies )

I do not know how to populate the ComboBox with the names of those files, and after that when pressing a button I need to interact with the name selected in the ComboBox.

I have absolutely no idea on how to do that. I do not beg for any code ( altho it will be well received ) I just want the guideline ( do "this" first they you can do "that" and at the end you do "that" ) and I will do all the rest. It is just I can not figure that out. Thank you all !

Comment: So you have successfully done retrieving the file names???

Comment: The names are the files in the folders, no, I have not managed to successfully retrieve the names :/

Answer (score 0):

First get the names of the files that is something like this:

```
string[] files=Directory.GetFiles("//path");
```

Now you have an array of all file names in the specific folder given above. Now take this string and populate it to the combo box that is something like this.

```
foreach(string file in files){
   comboBox1.Items.add(file);
}
```

After that you have to create the event behind the combo box. If you drag-drooped combo box, then you can make its event by going to properties. Then code something like this behind the item select event behind combo box.

```
protected void combobox(bla bla)
{
     if(comboBox1.SelectedItem == "An item")
          //Do whatever
      //it maybe selectedItem or selectedText or something like this
}
```

I code roughly so it may contain some errors.

Comment: Jamil thank you very much for the guideline, the code and the time and attention that you have given me ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the help given I have done:

```
public string seltest = null;
string group1 = GroupsDBForm.gone;
string[] tests1 =
            Directory.GetFiles("D:\\Riddler\\groups\\" + group1).Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path)).ToArray();
        foreach (string t1 in tests1)
        {
            test_list.Items.Add(group1+"\\"+t1);
        }
private void begin_test_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seltest = "D:\\Riddler\\groups\\" + test_list.Text;
        Do_Test_Form DoTest = new Do_Test_Form();
        DoTest.ShowPath = seltest;
        DoTest.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;
        DoTest.Show();
    }
```

( Those are the parts of the project connected to the issue, and because they are connected to other parts is might be lessunderstandeble what are the other names mentioned )

I know it is far from the best code but it works. I post it if this help another person with a close to this issue !

Thank you again Jamil!